# Passing data from a ui form component to included insertListing item

Tags: magento2, ajax, uicomponent, knockoutjs

Is it possible to pass data available in a UI component in the form of a `dataScope` item:

```
<field name="question">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Question</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">question</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question_id</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

to a listing UI component included in the component using a `insertListing` item:

```
<insertListing name="test_listing_insert">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="autoRender" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">question_id</item>
            <item name="ns" xsi:type="string">test_test_listing</item></item>
    </argument>
</insertListing>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So the way i ended up doing this was to use a form modifier for the data provider by using the Magento Catalog as a an example.

A modifier allows you to affect the meta or structure of the ui component json which is sent to the front end for rendering. 
see `Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/Related.php`

In order to filter the listing by the item id for what you are editing on the form, set a filter on the collection in the data provider for the listing using the request param for the form id. Then make sure in the get meta you set the imports and exports arrays with the following substituting  the id for your id:

```
'imports' => [
    'seeminglyArbitraryValue' => '${ $.provider }:data.form_id_field_name'
],
'exports' => [
    'seeminglyArbitraryValue' => '${ $.externalProvider }:params.form_id_field_name'
],
```

Comment: Is this solution still working? I need to do something similar on the product form with an InsertListing UI component - running Magento 2.4.3. So to clarify - to modify the json sent to the data provider to include, say a product id, I would set a form modifier for the product form?

Comment: @RobertDeBoer did you find any solution on this? I need to pass the id to the insert listing and show data only on that id.

Comment: @jwtea can you please check this question - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/363746/how-to-show-data-in-grid-based-on-url-parameter-in-magento-2-custom-form