# How to show data in grid based on url parameter in magento 2 custom form?

Tags: uicomponent, parameter, insertlisting, magento2.4.5p1

I created a custom form to save the data(category - table_category). In the form page i have a grid which shows Faqs related to the category. Currently i am getting all the faqs(table_faq), which are not filtered based on categories.

**Something same approach was implemented in customer address listing inside the customer form.**
[image]

I am passing the category id like below to the listing.

```
<fieldset name="faq_lists">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Faq List (Listing)</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <insertListing name="faq_lists">
        <settings>
            <externalData>id</externalData>
            <dataLinks>
                <exports>false</exports>
                <imports>true</imports>
            </dataLinks>
            <autoRender>true</autoRender>
            <selectionsProvider>
                ayakil_faq_faq_listing.ayakil_faq_faq_listing_data_source.columns.ids
            </selectionsProvider>
            <dataScope>ayakil_faq_faq_listing</dataScope>
            <ns>ayakil_faq_faq_listing</ns>
            <exports>
                <link name="faq_category_id">${ $.externalProvider }:params.faq_category_id</link>
            </exports>
        </settings>
    </insertListing>
</fieldset>
```

And in the listing xml i added

```
<filterUrlParams>
    <param name="faq_category_id">*</param>
</filterUrlParams>
```

But still all the faqs show in the grid. Not based on the category id its not filtering. How can i do this task?

**Update 1**
I have created a custom data provider and assign it on my listing.xml. My listing is reaching the data provider but not receiving the passed parameter there.

```
<insertListing name="insert_listing_example">
        <settings>
            <externalData>id</externalData>
            <dataLinks>
                <exports>false</exports>
                <imports>true</imports>
            </dataLinks>
            <autoRender>true</autoRender>
            <externalProvider>insert_listing_example.insert_listing_example_data_source</externalProvider>
            <selectionsProvider>insert_listing_example.insert_listing_example.columns.ids</selectionsProvider>
            <dataScope>insert_listing_example</dataScope>
            <ns>insert_listing_example</ns>
             <exports>
                <link name="faq_category_id">${ $.externalProvider }:params.faq_category_id</link>
            </exports>
            <imports>
                <link name="faq_category_id">${ $.provider}:data.faq_category_id</link>
            </imports>
        </settings>
    </insertListing>
```

My Listing xml file below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">insert_listing_example.insert_listing_example_data_source</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<settings>
    <spinner>columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>insert_listing_example.insert_listing_example_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>
<dataSource name="insert_listing_example_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
       <filterUrlParams>
            <param name="faq_category_id">*</param>
        </filterUrlParams>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">category_id</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    <dataProvider class="Ayakil\Faq\Ui\Component\Listing\Faq\DataProvider" name="insert_listing_example_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>faq_category_id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>faq_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
    <filters name="listing_filters"/>
</listingToolbar>
<columns name="columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="10">
        <settings>
            <indexField>faq_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>
    <column name="faq_id" sortOrder="20">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">ID</label>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="question" sortOrder="30">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Question</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
     <column name="answer" sortOrder="30">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Answer</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Ayakil\Faq\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\FaqActions">
        <settings>
            <indexField>faq_id</indexField>
            <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
            <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>
</columns>
```

Data Provider file

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\Faq\Ui\Component\Listing\Faq;

use Ayakil\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{ 
 private $request;
 public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    RequestInterface $request,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->context  = $context;
}
public function getData(): array
{
 $collection = $this->getCollection();
 $data['items'] = [];
 if ($this->request->getParam('faq_category_id')) {
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id', $this->request->getParam('faq_category_id'));
        $data = $collection->toArray();
    }
 return $data;
}
```

**Current view after this try.**
[image]
**Payload view**
[image]

Comment: Can you provide me whole module zip? I will solve it and update you here. Or send me on skype.

Answer (score 2):

Hello Mujahidh you can replace your **DataProvider** file code with below code and try

```
<?php
namespace Ayakil\Faq\Ui\Component\Listing\Faq;

use Ayakil\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CountryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;

class DataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    private $request;
    
    public $collectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        RequestInterface $request,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface $context,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getData(): array
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        $data['items'] = [];
        if ($this->request->getParam('faq_category_id')) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('category_id', ['eq' => $this->request->getParam('faq_category_id')]);
            $data = $collection->toArray();
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to pass the params from form to grid custom DataProvider and capture in in DataProvider. This answer part already in my question.

Comment: But here where do you define form?

Comment: <insertListing name="insert_listing_example"> this code part is define in side my form.

Comment: You get your faq_category_id in your Dataprovider file?

Comment: Not getting is my issue here, I might missing on insert listing and grid_listing some where.

Answer (score 2):

I get your problem, You want to add a grid that loads the data of Faq by the Faq_category_id in the Faq Category. Correct me if I am wrong!

if I am getting you right!

You are trying to get the param of faq_category_id in the data provider but there is no field in the grid, like faq_category_id so this shows a null grid (the data provider is not getting the faq_category_id from the form, it is searching for faq_category_id on the grid page)

I have another way to get filtered data on the grid.

**Step1:**  Add this fieldset to the listing (.XML file)

```
<fieldset name="faq_lists" sortOrder="60">
    <settings>
        <label translate="true">Assigned Banners</label>
    </settings>
    <htmlContent name="user_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <block name="faq_list" class="Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid"/>
    </htmlContent>
</fieldset>
```

**Setp2:** create Grid.php File Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml path and add the below code,

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml;

use Exception;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended;
use Magento\Backend\Helper\Data;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory; //load your collectionFactory

class Grid extends Extended
{
    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $collectionFactory;

    /**
     * Grid constructor.
     *
     * @param Context $context
     * @param Data $backendHelper
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context           $context,
        Data              $backendHelper,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory, 
        array             $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getGridUrl(): string //set your grid url
    {
        return $this->getUrl('customer/index/index', ['_current' => true]);// grid Url
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('customer');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id'); //add your primary key (Id)
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection() // load your collection with the custom filter
    {
        $id =  1; //$this->getRequest()->getParam('category_id');
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();

            $collection->addFieldToFilter('group_id', ['eq' => $id]); //add ur custom filter with your field id 
            $this->setCollection($collection);
        parent::_prepareCollection();
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @throws Exception
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns() // add column which you want to show in the form
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Id'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'firstname',
            [
                'header' => __('First Name'),
                'index' => 'firstname'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'lastname',
            [
                'header' => __('Last Name'),
                'index' => 'lastname'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'created_at',
            [
                'header' => __('created at'),
                'index' => 'created_at'
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

in this example, I loaded the customer data in the customer form with their group_id.

[image: grid look like this]
**Grid Look Like this**

Let me know if any Query,

**Thank You!**

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I want an approach to achieve this task using <insertlisting>, Where i am unable to get an answer any where. I too followed another way to achieve this. But still keep the bounty open to get an answer.

Comment: Hey! This link can help you to get your approach [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/189751/how-to-pass-data-to-another-ui-components-dataprovider)

Answer (score 0):

To Access the current category_id, i used dataPersister option.
set the category_id to a dataPersister variable on edit controller and access it from dataProvider file.

```
<?php 
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class Edit extends \Ayakil\Faq\Controller\Adminhtml\Faqcategory
{
  private $dataPersistorInterface; 

  public function __construct(
   ....
   DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistorInterface,
   ....
  ){
    $this->dataPersistorInterface =  $dataPersistorInterface;
   }
public function execute()
{
.......
    $this->dataPersistorInterface->set("current_faq_category", $model->getId());
........
}
}
```

And access from DataProvider file like below

```
$faqCatId = $this->dataPersistorInterface->get("current_faq_category");// Access the current category here
```

Answer (score 0):

## Insert Listing

```
  <fieldset>
        <settings>
            <level>1</level>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <label translate="true">Edit History</label>
        </settings>
       <insertListing name="edit_history_listing" component="Magento_Customer/js/form/components/insert-listing">
         <settings>
           <dataLinks>
             <exports>false</exports>
             <imports>true</imports>
           </dataLinks>
          <autoRender>true</autoRender>
          <externalProvider>edit_history_listing.edit_history_listing_data_source</externalProvider>
          <dataScope>edit_history_listing</dataScope>
          <ns>edit_history_listing</ns>
          <imports>
            <link name="id">${ $.provider }:data.id</link>
          </imports>
          <exports>
            <link name="id">${ $.externalProvider }:params.id</link>
          </exports>
         </settings>
       </insertListing>
    </fieldset>
```

## Listing (edit_history_listing.xml)

```
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">edit_history_listing.edit_history_listing_data_source</item></item></argument>

<settings>
    <spinner>columns</spinner>
    <deps>
        <dep>edit_history_listing.edit_history_listing_data_source</dep>
    </deps>
</settings>

<dataSource name="edit_history_listing_data_source" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider">
    <settings>
        <filterUrlParams>
            <param name="id">*</param>
        </filterUrlParams>
        <storageConfig>
            <param name="indexField" xsi:type="string">edit_id</param>
        </storageConfig>
        <updateUrl path="mui/index/render"/>
    </settings>
    <aclResource>Magento_Cms::page</aclResource>
    <dataProvider class="Codilar\Demo\Model\DataProvider\EditHistory\EditHistory"
                  name="edit_history_listing_data_source">
        <settings>
            <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
            <primaryFieldName>edit_id</primaryFieldName>
        </settings>
    </dataProvider>
</dataSource>

<columns name="columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids" sortOrder="1">
        <settings>
            <indexField>edit_id</indexField>
        </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>

    <column name="edit_id" sortOrder="2">
        <settings>
            <filter>textRange</filter>
            <label translate="true">ID</label>
            <sorting>asc</sorting>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="name" sortOrder="3">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">name</label>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="phone" sortOrder="4">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Phone</label>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="email" sortOrder="5">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Email</label>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="dob" sortOrder="6">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Dob</label>
        </settings>
    </column>

    <column name="address" sortOrder="7">
        <settings>
            <filter>text</filter>
            <label translate="true">Address</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
    <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="150">
        <settings>
            <dataType>date</dataType>
            <label translate="true">Edited At</label>
        </settings>
    </column>
</columns>
```

## DataProvider

class EditHistory extends AbstractDataProvider
{
/**
* @var RequestInterface
*/
private $request;

```
/**
 * EditHistory constructor.
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 * @param RequestInterface $request
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
    RequestInterface $request,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    $this->request = $request;
}

/**
 * @return array
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function getData()
{
    $collection = $this->getCollection();
    if ($this->request->getParam('id')){
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('id', $this->request->getParam('id'));
        $data = $collection->toArray();
    } else {
        $data = $collection->toArray();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

}

## If You want Code Check git Repo

- https://github.com/sanjay-code-debug/Magento_Task